# vb.net windows form select query using postgresql server

Tags: vb.net, postgresql

I am new in vb.net, how do i conduct select query in my  windows forms using postgresql server?

this is my connection, (actually i dont know if this is working but i didnt receive any error and the message box appear if i button is clicked)

here is code so far

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim MyCon As New Odbc.OdbcConnection

        MyCon.ConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI};database=*****;server=localhost;port=5432;uid=postgres;sslmode=disable;readonly=0;protocol=7.4;User ID=******;password=*****;"
        MyCon.Open()
        If MyCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            MsgBox("Connected To PostGres", MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxSetForeground)

        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .Net we have `Using...End Using` blocks that will close and dispose objects that use unmanaged code. Connections fall into this type of object; any object class that has a .Dispose method.

You can pass your connection string directly to the constructor of the connection.

We also have `Try...Catch...Finally....End Try` for exception handling.

To test your connection:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Using MyCon As New Odbc.OdbcConnection("Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI};database=*****;server=localhost;port=5432;uid=postgres;sslmode=disable;readonly=0;protocol=7.4;User ID=******;password=*****;")
            MyCon.Open()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

For help with the connection string itself check https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql/

There are several ways to query your database in **ADO.net**. Study up on ADO.net. The following is one way.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Try
        Using MyCon As New Odbc.OdbcConnection("Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI};database=*****;server=localhost;port=5432;uid=postgres;sslmode=disable;readonly=0;protocol=7.4;User ID=******;password=*****;"),
                cmd As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("Select * From SomeTable;", MyCon)
            MyCon.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```